# How to change background color of an item based on the click in AngularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, onfocus

I have listed a number of `<div>`s using ng-repeat.

When I click on one `<div>` (div1) background color becomes blue, and if I click on other div (div2) - div1-background-color becomes white as it was at the beginning and div2-background-color becomes blue.
Here is my html:

```
<div  ng-repeat="folder in vm.folders track by $index" >
    <span>{{folder.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What the blue background is supposed to mean? Is it kind of item selection or what?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: yes it's kind of item selection

Comment: @Serhiy try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39347164/6608101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("ap",[]);

app.controller("con",function($scope){
   $scope.changeIndex = function(index){
    $scope.selected = index;
  }
});
```

```css
.blue{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
<div ng-repeat="n in [10, 20, 30, 40] track by $index">
  <div ng-class="{blue: selected==$index}" ng-click="changeIndex($index)">{{n}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<div  ng-repeat="folder in vm.folders track by $index" ng-click="setSelected($index)" ng-class="{selected : $index === selectedfolder }">
    <span>{{folder.name}}</span>
</div>
```

**js**

```
  $scope.selectedfolder = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function(selectedfolder ) {
       $scope.selectedfolder = selectedfolder ;
    }
```

**css**

```
.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign each div a function on click that saves the last clicked div id's. Then you have to use the ng-class directive to set a blue-background class to the div if his id is the current one.

```
$scope.setCurrent = function(index){
   $scope.currentId = index;
}

<div ng-repeat="folder in vm.folders track by $index" ng-click="setCurrent($index)" ng-class="{selected : currentId == $index}" >
    <span>{{folder.name}}</span>
</div>
```